# Math.Random, calculating Percentages

Tags: java, percentage

:D 
I'm currently making an RPG, made the combat system, if a player attack makes contact with the enemy it deals damage, now what I want to do is add critical strike into the mix and blocking.

How it should work? well first it will roll the chances of the monster blocking based on his blocking chance, if it blocks the incoming damage gets reduced to zero, if it doesnt it rolls the chance of critical strike based on the players critical strike chance, if its critical it will deal x bonus amount of damage based on the players critical strike multiplier.

Now what I want to know is how to calculate the percentage chance, I've seen several posts but they usually turn the percentage into a whole number, and probably my players will start with low rolls as 1.7% or 3.9%, but not 1-2-3-5, flat percentages. Anyone got suggestions on how to make it?

so far the code goes like this:

```
public class Player{
private double criticalStrikeChance = 0.009; <--- thats 0.9% chance.
private double criticalStrikeMultiplier = 1.2; <--- thats 120% moar damage

public double getCritStrk(){
   return criticalStrikeChance;
                       }

}

public class Monster(){
private double blockingChance = 0.3; <--- thats 30%
private double blockingReduction = 0.75; <--- thats 75% reduced damage when blocking

}


public class Game(){

public void checkIfDamaged(){

if(intersects){

       // blockroll should be done here based on the monster chance

       if(blockRoll >= minimum he had to roll){
         //means its successfull
          monster.getHit(0); //PEANUT DAMAGE ACHIEVED GREAT SUCCESS 
          }else{

           //Critical strike chance should be rolled here based on player
           //chance
            if(critstrike successful){ 
               incdamage + (incdamage * player.criticalStrikeMultiplier;
                      monster.getHit(incdamage);
                                  }
          }else{//Crit didnt roll with cinnamon
                 monster.getHit(player.getDamage);
               }


       }

}

}
```

Ok so that's pretty much it as pseudo-code because my code looks way different but thats simple and should give you guys an idea on how it should work, so please help me senpais! I SHALL GIVE YOU CHOCO COOKIES + a nice shield with 100% block rate :D to whoever halps me!

Comment: Subject is totally misleading to the actual question. Also reduce amount of code

Comment: My bad about the title, it seems the system confused a previous question I already asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking to roll a random percentage, you can use the `Random` class in java.

```
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    Double pickedNumber = rand.nextDouble();
```

Running that, will result in `pickedNumber` being some `double` between 0 and 1. For example:

```
0.3650998187710377
```

Then check if that percentage is less than whatever your block/crit chance is. For example:

```
if(pickedNumber < blockChange)
    //doBlock();
```

A full example, for a test case could be something like:

```
private static Random rand = new Random(); 

public static void main(String[] args) {

    double blockChance = .5; // 50% chance to block the attack

    Double pickedNumber = rand.nextDouble(); // Roll to see if we block the attack

    System.out.println(pickedNumber); // output roll for debug purposes

    if(pickedNumber < blockChance){ // if the attack was blocked
        System.out.println("Blocked"); // do block logic
    }else{ // if the attack wasn't blocked
        System.out.println("Damaged"); // do damage logic
    }
}
```

Which gave me the output:

```
0.2768592334674802
Blocked
```

And:

```
0.8762124334674802
Damaged
```

Comment: But it wouldnt be an accurate chance, since there are infinite numbers between 0 and 1. Example: I need 0.03, I can roll 1k+ numbers from 0.01 to 0.03 thanks to their big size like the one in your example: 0.3650998187710377.

Comment: Well nevermind, I'll go and test it out, thanks though for your help! here have a choco cookie! n.n

Comment: You are stating that you want to reduce the accuracy of the roll? I would not suggest doing that. Don't check for the exact number that is there block chance, if you do that, you have a 1/1000 chance to block every time. Instead, check if it is LESS THAN their block chance. For example, if you have a 3% block chance, that means that if you roll a 1,2, or 3 you would block, 4-100 you would be damaged.

Comment: Glad to have helped! Let me know if you have any other questions. Feel free to make my answer as the answer to your problem if I have answered it to your needs.

Comment: Indeed,I made it my answer :D. Yesh I shall search for yer knowledge if I need to make another question n.n thanks a bunch! God Bless.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:
To get 0.75:

```
if (Math.random() < 0.75) {
   //do this with probability 0.75
}
```